# Menu con distintas ejecuciones en java

Tags: java

estoy haciendo un ejercicio de clase, os pongo el enunciado y os explico.

Realizar un programa que nos permita aceptar números mayores o iguales a cero por teclado hasta que se introduzca un número negativo. En ese momento se verá en pantalla el siguiente menú:

```
1-Suma de los números pares introducidos.
2-Media de los números pares introducidos. (con dos decimales)
3-Mayor nº impar introducido.
4-Cuántos números hemos introducido.
5-Cuantos números de los introducidos han sido ceros, cuántos han sido pares y cuantos impares.
6.-Salir.
```

El menú (con los valores ya introducidos) se repetirá hasta que el usuario decida “Salir”.

En el paso primero no se si tengo que acumular los números introducidos, yo he puesto que sea así, aun que igual lo tengo mal, los he guardado en un `array` para el menú. La cosa es que estoy intentando hacer el `switch` con el menu, pero no se como  hacer esas operaciones, si van dentro del case o fuera. Mi segunda duda es como visualizar las opciones para el que usuario antes de dar en alguna, vea lo que hace previamente.os dejo lo que he hecho.

```
public class Ejercicio4 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Progama que nos permite aceptar numeros mayores o iguales a cero y si no, aparecerá un menú.");
        System.out.println("----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n");
        Scanner teclado;
        int numero;
        List<Integer> lista = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        int salir = 6;
        int opcion = 0;
        try {

            do {
                System.out.print("Introduce un número: ");
                teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
                numero = teclado.nextInt();
                if (numero >= 0) {

                    lista.add(numero);
                }

            } while (numero >= 0);
            if (numero < 0) {
                while (opcion != salir) {
                    System.out.println("--------- Menú de opciones --------");
                    System.out.println("1-Suma de los números pares introducidos ");
                    System.out.println("2-Media de los números pares introducidos. (con dos decimales) ");
                    System.out.println("3-Mayor nº impar introducido. ");
                    System.out.println("4-Cuántos números hemos introducido. ");
                    System.out.println("5-Cuantos números de los introducidos han sido ceros, cuántos han sido pares y cuantos impares ");
                    System.out.println("6-Salir ");

                    teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
                    opcion = teclado.nextInt();
                    switch (opcion) {
                        //1-Suma de los números pares introducidos
                        case 1:

                            int suma = 0;
                            for (int i = 0; i < lista.size(); i++) {

                                int num = lista.get(i);
                                if (num % 2 == 0) {
                                    suma = num + suma;
                                }
                            }
                            System.out.println("La suma de los números pares introducidos son" + suma);
                            break;

                        //2-Media de los números pares introducidos. (con dos decimales)
                        case 2:
                            double media = 0;
                            int x = 0;
                            suma = 0;
                            for (int i = 0; i < lista.size(); i++) {
                                int num = lista.get(i);

                                if (num % 2 == 0) {
                                    suma = num + suma;
                                    x++;
                                }

                            }
                            media = suma / x;
                            System.out.println("La media de los números pares introducidos son " + Math.round(media * 100d) / 100d + "\n");

                            break;

                        //3-Mayor nº impar introducido.
                        case 3:
                            suma = 0;
                            int max = 0;
                            for (int i = 0; i < lista.size(); i++) {

                                int num = lista.get(i);
                                if (!(num % 2 == 0)) {
                                    if (num > max) {
                                        max = num;
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            System.out.println("La media de los números pares introducidos son " + max);
                            break;
                        //4-Cuántos números hemos introducido.
                        case 4:
                            int numeros = 0;
                            for (int i = 0; i < lista.size(); i++) {

                                numeros++;
                            }
                            System.out.println("Cuantos números hemos introducido " + numeros);

                            break;
                        //5-Cuantos números de los introducidos han sido ceros, cuántos han sido pares y cuantos impares.
                        case 5:

                            int pares = 0;
                            int impares = 0;
                            int ceros =0;
                            int cero=0;
                            for (int i = 0; i < lista.size(); i++) {

                                int num = lista.get(i);
                                if (num % 2 == 0) {
                                    pares++;
                                }else if(!(num % 2 == 0)&& num!=0){
                                impares++;
                                } 
                                 if (num==0){
                                ceros++;
                                } 
                                }
                            System.out.println("Los números pares han sido : " + pares);
                            System.out.println("Los números impares han sido : " + impares);
                            System.out.println("Los números cero han sido : " + ceros);
                            break;
                        //6.-Salir.
                        case 6:

                            break;
                    }
                }

            }

        } catch (InputMismatchException ime) {
            System.out.println("¡Cuidado! Solo puedes insertar números. ");

        }

    }

}`introducir el código aquí`
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            System.out.println("Progama que nos permite aceptar numeros mayores o iguales a cero y si no, aparecerá un menú.");
            System.out.println("----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n");
            Scanner teclado;
            int numero;
            List lista = new ArrayList();

            int salir = 6;
            int opcion = 0;
            try {
                System.out.print("Introduce un número: ");
                teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
                numero = teclado.nextInt();
                do {

                    lista.add(numero);
                } while (numero >= 0);
                if (numero < 0) {
                    while (opcion != salir) {
                        System.out.print("Elige una opción: ");

                        switch (opcion) {
                            //1-Suma de los números pares introducidos
                            case 1: 
                            System.out.print("La suma de los números pares introducidos son" +(lista%2==0) +lista);
                            break;

                            //2-Media de los números pares introducidos. (con dos decimales)
                            case 2: break;  
                            //3-Mayor nº impar introducido.
                            case 3: break;    
                            //4-Cuántos números hemos introducido.
                            case 4: break;
                            //5-Cuantos números de los introducidos han sido ceros, cuántos han sido pares y cuantos impares.
                            case 5: break;   
                            //6.-Salir.
                            case 6: break;
                        }
                    }

                }
            } catch (InputMismatchException ime) {
                System.out.println("¡Cuidado! Solo puedes insertar números. ");

            }

        }

    }
```

Comment: para el tema de Switch por favor refiere a los tutoriales de Oracle en Relacion al [Switch Statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html) (basicamente tiene que poner lo que hace despues del `case`  con relacion a como mostrar un mensaje antes de que se solicite un "input" mi recomendacion es hacer un Metodo y lo llamas antes de `System.out.print("Elige una opción: ");` [Metodos en Java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html)

Comment: Revertí la edición de la pregunta, pues con esta las respuestas que has recibido quedan sin sentido. Si tu problema original está resuelto, considera aceptar una de las respuestas y siempre es bienvenido que publiques una nueva pregunta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Con respecto al case 5, podrías preguntar al principio si es 0. En caso de que NO lo sea, recien ahí preguntas si es par, y luego si es impar. De esta forma, si es 0 no va a contar como par.

```
case 5:

int pares = 0;
int impares = 0;
int ceros = 0;
int cero = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < lista.size(); i++) {
    int num = lista.get(i);
    if (num == 0) {
        ceros++;
    } else if (num % 2 == 0) {
        pares++;
    } else {
        impares++;
    } 
}
System.out.println("Los números pares han sido : " + pares);
System.out.println("Los números impares han sido : " + impares);
System.out.println("Los números cero han sido : " + ceros);
break;
```

De esta forma, la unica forma en la que pregunte si es par es que no sea 0, por lo que no va a contar como par.

Espero que te sirva!!

PD: No entiendo el funcionamiento de la variable "cero".

PD2: Perdon por la identacion, es la primera vez que respondo y no se como se hace =).

Answer (score 0):

Te pongo un ejemplo de mas o menos (disculpa por los fallos de identacion o puntos y comas que lo he hecho en el editor este asi de cabeza. Te he puedo un ejemplo ponieno el menu en una clase aparte para que no queda tanto código pero puedes hacerlo ahí mismo, al final es lo mismo. El switch dentro de cada case tienes que crear la lógica que hayas elegido en el menú. Le pasas la opción y depende de lo que hayas introducido hará una cosa u otra. Una buena práctica es incluir el default en el switch, cosa que yo no he hecho pero puedes investigar sobre ello. Espero que te haya ayudado, cualquer duda ya sabes, por aquí andamos!

```
  public class Ejercicio4 {
    Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            System.out.println("Progama que nos permite aceptar numeros mayores o iguales a cero y si no, aparecerá un menú.");
            System.out.println("----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n");
        int numero=0;
        int opcion = 0;
        List lista = new ArrayList();
        try {

           do {
                System.out.print("Introduce un número: ");
                numero = teclado.nextInt();
                lista.add(numero);
            } while (numero >= 0);

            do{
            opcion = menu()
             switch (opcion) {
                        //1-Suma de los números pares introducidos
                        case 1: 
                         //Logica del caso 1
                        System.out.print("La suma de los números pares introducidos son" +(lista%2==0) +lista);
                        break;

                        //2-Media de los números pares introducidos. (con dos decimales)
                        case 2: //Logica del caso 2 break;  
                        //3-Mayor nº impar introducido.
                        case 3: //Logica del caso 3 break;    
                        //4-Cuántos números hemos introducido.
                        case 4: break;
                        //5-Cuantos números de los introducidos han sido ceros, cuántos han sido pares y cuantos impares.
                        case 5: break;   
                        //6.-Salir.
                        case 6:
                         System.out.print("Hasta la vista baby!");
                        break;
                    }
            }while (opcion != 6); 


        } catch (InputMismatchException ime) {
            System.out.println("¡Cuidado! Solo puedes insertar números. ");

        }

    }

}

public static Integer menu(){

Integer op;

System.out.println("Menu");
System.out.println("1.Sumar");
System.out.println("2.blabla");
System.out.println("3.Salir");
System.out.println("elige una opcion:");
op = teclado.nextInt();

return op;
}
```

Comment: Ha sido de gran ayuda, aun que no lo haya hecho igual. He puesto mi solución arriba. Por cierto una pregunta, el case 5, com podría separar el 0 para que no me lo coja como par?

Comment: Me alegro que haya podido ayudarte, para eso estamos. Pues para evitar que no te sume el 0 a los pares es muy sencillo simplemente en la condición del if especificarle que ignore los 0 así:

if (num % 2 == 0 && num != 0) 
                                    pares++;

o también (que viene a ser lo mismo:

if (num > 0 && num % 2 == 0) {
                                    pares++;
                                }
Un Saludo!

Answer (score 0):

> La cosa es que estoy intentando hacer el switch con el menu, pero no se como hacer esas operaciones, si van dentro del case o fuera.

tomemos como base el [tutorial de Switch de Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html) tenemos que Switch se utiliza de forma que tenemos `switch (opcion)` y dependiendo del valor de `opcion` ingresa a un `case` si no existe un `case con el valor` se ingresa a `default` (si esta definido)

```
switch (opcion) {
    case 1: 
        //codigo a Ejecutar si se da el Case 1
        //Suma de los números pares introducidos
        //NOTA el Break se utiliza para salir del switch.
        break;
    case 2:
        //codigo a Ejecutar si se da el Case 2
        //2-Media de los números pares introducidos. (con dos decimales)
        break;  
     case 3: 
        //codigo a Ejecutar si se da el Case 3
        //3-Mayor nº impar introducido.
        break;
     case 4:
        //codigo a Ejecutar si se da el Case 
        //4-Cuántos números hemos introducido.             
        break;            
     case 5:
        //5-Cuantos números de los introducidos han sido ceros, cuántos han sido pares y cuantos impares.
        break;
     case 6: 
        //6.-Salir.
        break;
     default:
         //codigo a Ejecutar si el valor no esta en case 
        // que hacer si opcion no es ninguno de los valores del case. 
        break;
```

}

> Mi segunda duda es como visualizar las opciones para el que usuario
>   antes de dar en alguna, vea lo que hace previamente.

para ello se debe usar [Metodos](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html), [Metodos link 2](http://codigoprogramacion.com/cursos/java/87-curso-javautilizando-metodos-en-java.html) los Metodos son bloques de codigo que permiten tener funcionalides Reutilisables. por tanto en un ejemplo:

```
//esto es una constante por tanto definida como final
private static final int SALIR = 6;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Progama que nos permite aceptar numeros mayores o iguales a cero y si no, aparecerá un menú.");
    System.out.println("----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
    System.out.println();
    Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
    ArrayList<Integer> lista = leerNumeros(teclado);
    Acciones(teclado, lista);
}

private static void mostrarMenu() {
    System.out.println("------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
    System.out.println("Menu:");
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("1-Suma de los números pares introducidos.");
    System.out.println("2-Media de los números pares introducidos. (con dos decimales)");
    System.out.println("3-Mayor nº impar introducido.");
    System.out.println("4-Cuántos números hemos introducido.");
    System.out.println("5-Cuantos números de los introducidos han sido ceros, cuántos han sido pares y cuantos impares.");
    System.out.println("6.-Salir.");
    System.out.println("------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
    System.out.println();
}

private static void Acciones(Scanner teclado, ArrayList lista) {
    int opcion;
    do {
        mostrarMenu();
        opcion = teclado.nextInt();
        //...
        //switch
        //...
    } while (opcion != SALIR);
}

private static ArrayList<Integer> leerNumeros(Scanner teclado) {
    System.out.println("------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Ingreso de numeros, para terminar el ingreso de numeros ingrese un numero negativo");
    System.out.println();
    ArrayList<Integer> valores = new ArrayList<>();
    int numero;
    do {
        System.out.print("Introduce un número: ");
        try {
            numero = teclado.nextInt();
            if (numero >= 0) {
                valores.add(numero);
            }
        } catch (InputMismatchException err) {
            numero=0;
            teclado.next();//descarta el valor que "no es valido"
            teclado.reset();
            System.out.println("Valor Invalido, Si desea salir Ingrese un valor negativo.");
        }
    } while (numero >= 0);
    return valores;
}
```

nota: el codigo que se provee tiene errores de sintaxis o logica:

`opcion` nunca cambia de valor. siempre es `0`

`System.out.print("La suma de los números pares introducidos son" +(lista%2==0) +lista);`
la lista no es un "numero" por tanto no puedes realizar una operacion sobre el objecto de lista `(lista%2==0)` y ademas `+lista` puede no dar el resultado util para ser desplegado.